# Which classes are absolutely necessary to get a Java VM running?

Tags: java, class, language-agnostic, jvm

What is the smallest subset of classes with which a Java VM is able to start up?

I guess things like Object, String and the primitves are absolutely required because they are hard-wired in many parts of the VM.

I'm interested in how big the dependencies between the JVM and the JDK are.

The basic question I'm wondering about is:

> If I would decide to distribute a JVM
>   with a different programming language
>   and different standard libraries, how
>   much of the "Java" classes do I have
>   to carry around to make the JVM happy?

Comment: Probably depends what you mean by "start up" the VM. Does it have to include a classloader plus dependencies, to load a program?

Comment: Why is this tagged `language-agnostic`?

Comment: Because the JVM only executes bytecode. There are multiple languages and compilers which can generate that bytecode.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Good question! I would say only the classloader which bootstraps the VM... But I'm not totally sure what's the best way to define "start up", so your question is a very valid one.

Comment: Except that the answer will inevitably be language specific, not language agnostic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to find out is to try it and see; e.g. use `java -verbose.` to run the minimal program in a variety of JVM hosted languages.

But the answer is likely to be:

- JVM version specific, and
- programming language specific.

I should also point out that the answer(s) you get won't be of any practical use (... unless you plan to create a cut-down JRE.  And if that is the case, read the followup below.)

> Do you know if all of the classes are strictly necessary or does the VM also preload classes which it expects to be used in all cases by applications?

The JVM does not preload things on that basis.  Rather, it loads the dependency closure of that your code staticly depends on.  Depending on what classes your application uses, this may result in classes being loaded that aren't actually used.  The Sun engineers have done a lot of work to try and reduce this effect over the years, but it doubtless still happens to some extent.

**FOLLOW UP**

Reading between the lines, it seems that the intent is to create a cut-down JVM package to support the runtime requirements of some other language.  If so, consider these points:

- There are licensing requirements on what you can do with Java *vis-a-vis* the creation of cut-down versions.  Specifically, Java, JVM and JRE are trademarked terms, and Oracle *could* come after you if you use them in the context of a cut-down JRE.  (I'm not saying you cannot do it, but you *do* need to check the legal aspects for yourself.)
- There are definitely support issues.  For instance, you need to track any relevant Java / JVM security issues and patches and create new versions of your base platform as reuired.
- If you intend to provide any way for application programs in your new language to call Java libraries, then using a cut-down JRE could be a serious pain in the backside for some users.  Especially if you package your stuff in a way that means they have to use your cut-down JRE.
- There are tools in a JRE / JDK that could be useful to you / your users.  Tools like profilers, debuggers, the JAR command, and so on.  Your JRE would need to include all classes needed to run them.

Finally, a 100Mb download is not a significant issue for the VAST MAJORITY of users.  And if it is, you could make a bit of money to support your project by selling installer DVDs.

Focus on whatever it is you are really trying to do here ... and leave the installer optimization to when you've got a something of production quality to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the command:

```
java -verbose
```

It will show you every class it loads in order to start the VM. If you add `-verbose` when you start a java program you will get a complete list of what that program needs to start. But this does not include any further classes it may need as it does it's work.

Why do you need to know what classes are needed?

Comment: Do you know if all of the classes are strictly necessary or does the VM also preload classes which it expects to be used in all cases by applications? I wonder how big the dependencies between the JVM and the JDK are. The basic question I'm wondering about is: "If I would decide to distribute a JVM with a different programming language and different standard libraries, how much of the "Java" classes do I have to carry around to make the JVM happy?"

Comment: It's not really going to be a question about starting the VM. It's going to be a question about what does your other programming language need. The ultimate answer I think is that what is needed totally depends on the program you are starting the VM for. If you are implementing some sort of language then you cannot predict what will be needed so you will need to supply everything. Why would you want to trim it down? Or is this just a technical exercise? :-)

Comment: If you run this experiment, and ship only those classes that wind up in this list, you'll undoubtedly find that there are classes on the list that have methods (that weren't called at startup time) that construct objects of types that aren't on the list. In other words, even if your VM starts up, the classes that you shipped won't be a self-contained set, and they'll likely be broken by other missing classes.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pull apart a 7000 class application to see which ones are essential.  If you did, there is no way you could guarentee the JVM would not fail at some random point in the future? Worse if it blew up for any reason, the finger is likely to be pointed at you first until you can prove it had nothing to do with removing the classes.

If you are using a mobile device and need to save capacity, I suggest you use the JME.  However if you are using a desktop where 200 MB costs less than one penny, is it really worth the risk?  If it blows up will it cost you more than a penny, I suspect it will.

An analogy, you are walking along a major road and you see what might be a penny on the other side.  Do you cross the road through heavy traffic to get it?  I suggest you just keep on walking.

EDIT: If you want a cut down version of Java you can try the embedded version.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/index.html

It has a 32 MB and 70 MB variety.

Comment: 200MB download might easily cost more than a penny *per download*, if you're the poor sucker running the server this thing is on.

Comment: @Steve, You have make assumptions about what software should be installed first, e.g. the OS must be installed, and in this case Java must be installed.

Comment: @Steve, I pitty anyone who installs this special version of Java and then tries to run a regular Java applet or program.  They won't know where to start to fix it.

Comment: @Peter: If I was bundling a cut-down JVM as a runtime for my own language, then I would not install it into "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-whatever", so it would not clash with "real Java". Anyone who goes out of their way to try to run a Java app using the cut-down VM gets what they deserve. You might as well say that you pity anyone who installs J2SE and then tries to run an app that uses classes from J2EE. I mean, it's a personal tragedy, sure, but they'll recover. The fix is to run Java apps using Java, and run "soclang" apps using the "soclang runtime", which just so happens to be a JVM too.

Comment: @Steve, this is potentially useful if you assume the client has no need for Java or is particular resistant to the idea of installing.  If however, you have clients willing to install Java or need it for some other purpose, you will have effectively increased the download size (as they need the standard Java and your Java)  rather than reducing it.

Comment: @Peter: increased it by how much? We don't know unless we know the answer to this question, how big the Java-based runtime would be with the unnecessary classes removed. And how much user-convenience do we gain by satisfying our own JVM dependency? Again, unknown. So it's not possible to rule out the approach, and this is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Steve, creating an unsupportable version of Java will not increase user-convenience at all.  Its not an unknown. ;)

Comment: @Peter: it's not an unsupportable version of Java, it's a tool for a job. There's no need for the end-user to know or care that Java is involved at all, which is why it at least has the potential to be convenient. If I embed Lua or Python in a computer game, nobody hangs around saying, "ah, well, you haven't included the command-line Lua executable, or all the standard Python libraries, so users won't be able to run their own Lua/Python programs". It really does all depend whether this "coslang" distribution is presented to the user as a JVM-hosted language, or not.

Comment: ... and of course there could in theory be separate distributions. There could be one that's explicitly JVM-hosted, the way you want, for people who want to run it on whatever Java they have installed. Perhaps simultaneously with their own Java and Clojure code, and perhaps with a means to call arbitrary Java code from "soclang". Then there could be a stand-alone distribution, that perhaps has absolutely no need to ship with java.awt.Robot.

Comment: Anyway, if you're absolutely certain that there is no possible reason to ship a JVM that excludes any standard libraries, then do please tell Google, so that they can stop wasting time messing about with Dalvik and Android ;-)

Comment: Google ship Android for commercial reasons, I don't see any technical advantage in Android, in fact it may be 2-3 times slower. http://blogs.oracle.com/javaseembedded/2010/11/how_does_android_22s_performance_stack_up_against_java_se_embedded.html

Comment: Changing the underlying runtime is a violation of the license agreement, however Google wanted to brand their own solution.  Not sure Oracle would come after you for violating the license agreement, but you never know...

Answer (score 0):

IANAL, but you may risk being sued by Oracle if you strip down the `java.*` classes, because Sun/Oracle's public patent grant for JDK patents requires that you implement the full `java.*` interfaces, and that you do so compatibly with the standard. (I think this is part of what the Google suit hinges on.)

Aside from that, I think the [Project Jigsaw developers](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) are having a non-trivial time deciding what belongs in the base JDK install, and what belongs in a module. I recall reading a blog post (can't find it now) about some problems breaking circular dependancies between things that should be in modules (XML, IIRC) and the base install.